# Left Join on CTE and Subquery doesn't NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Im trying to do a left join between a CTE and subquery where i should get null values on the permission that the user/role doesn't have. The expectation is that will return null in some of the User field.

```
WITH CTE
 ([APP_Permission_Name])
AS
(SELECT DISTINCT UP.[APP_Permission_Name]
FROM [ADMINS].[APP_ROLE_PERMISSION] URP
INNER JOIN [ADMINS].[APP_ROLE] UR ON URP.[APP_Role_ID]=UR.[APP_Role_ID]
INNER JOIN [ADMINS].[APP_PERMISSION] UP ON URP.[APP_Permission_Id]=UP.[APP_Permission_Id])

SELECT DISTINCT CTE.[APP_Permission_Name], a.[APP_Computer_User_Id]
FROM CTE 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [APP_Permission_Name], UU.[APP_Computer_User_Id]
                FROM [ADMINS].[APP_USER] UU
                INNER JOIN [ADMINS].[APP_USER_ROLE] UUR ON UU.[APP_User_Id]=UUR.[APP_User_Id]
                INNER JOIN [ADMINS].[APP_ROLE_PERMISSION] RP ON UUR.[APP_Role_ID]=RP.[APP_Role_ID]
                INNER JOIN [ADMINS].[APP_ROLE] UR ON RP.[APP_Role_ID]=UR.[APP_Role_ID]
                INNER JOIN [ADMINS].[APP_PERMISSION] UP ON RP.[APP_Permission_Id]=UP.[APP_Permission_Id])a
    ON CTE.[APP_Permission_Name]=a.[APP_Permission_Name]
--ORDER BY a.[APP_Computer_User_Id]
```

The result would look something like this:

[APP_Permission_Name]   [APP_Computer_User_Id]
Administration-Read User1
Corrections-Read    User1
Maintenance-Read    User1
MasterData-Read User1
Payments-Read   User1
Reconciliation-Read User1

The query should output rows where the user will result to null.

Comment: Based on your description, your join is backwards.

Comment: I would suggest that you ask *another* question and include sample data and desired results.  Often, a non-functioning query does a very poor job of explaining what someone wants to do.

Comment: Added sample data

Comment: Would you mind making a http://sqlfiddle.com/ with some data?